# Get an element and its parent ONLY, using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to use the `find_all` function of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to retrieve all `<li>` tag but also their parent.

```
<div name="div1">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
</div>
```

If I try with this code:

```
tags = soup.find_all("li")
print tags[0].parent
```

This will print:

```
<div name="div1">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
</div>
```

Because the parent contains the two `<li>` tags.

What I expect is:

```
<div name="div1">
    <li>Test 1</li>
</div>
```

How to solve this issue please?

Comment: First show your code.

Comment: @furas I have no code. It is just `tags = soup.find_all("li")` and then, what to do? If if do `for tag in tags: print(tag.parent)` this will return twice the `div` and the two `li`, while I only want the div and the first li, then the div and the second li.

Comment: You have to lines - it is code - put it in question.

Comment: findall finds all the tags, what were you expecting?

Comment: Children are part of parent ?  Did you expect empty parent ?

Comment: I edited my question with a bit of code, I hope it is more understandable.

Comment: You are looking for parents, but parent is only one and it has two children - I thing you can only create new parent and add first `li` then creat another parent and add second `li`

Comment: BeautifulSoup returns a reference to the parent in the current document - so it will still have all of its children. If you really want the parent and only the current li child, you'll have to create a new document and copy them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you supposedly want to by replicating the parent for each list element and wrapping the element in it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """<div name="div1">
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        </div>"""

def clone(soup, tag):
   newtag = soup.new_tag(tag.name)
   for attr in tag.attrs:
      newtag[attr] = tag[attr]
   return newtag

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
tags = soup.find_all("li")
for tag in tags:
   print tag.wrap(clone(soup, tag.parent))
```

Comment: Great answer but I think it should add the li element to the cloned element also.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of, using a loop to know every attribute and recreate them. It is not handy, but it seems to be the only solution. Thank you, I will accept your answer if nobody has another idea.